# HTML javascript function issue. [object HTMLInputElement] error output

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml

I am trying to make a simple html page with two text boxes and an a button that adds the two numbers together when clicked. In my output, I am only getting `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

```js
function addNumbers(A, B){
  var answer = A + B;
  document.getElementById("testResult").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="15" id="varA">
<input type="text" value="30" id="varB">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNumbers(varA, varB)">
<h1 id="testResult"></h1>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried changing `.innerHTML` to `.value` already but then I get nothing at all as a result.

Comment: `varA` is the `input` element, not its value, which would be `varA.value`. However, you're going to need to change that to a number before adding it together, or else you'll end up with string concatenation.

Comment: Note `input` elements have no content, so you can use `<input ...>` or `<input ... />`, but not `<input ...></input>`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the mathematical sum and not the string concatenation.  If that's the case, you can use the following:

UPDATE based on comment:

```js
function addNumbers(elem1, elem2) {
  var a = document.getElementById(elem1).value;
  var b = document.getElementById(elem2).value;
  var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
  document.getElementById("testResult").innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="15" id="varA">
<input type="text" value="30" id="varB">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNumbers('varA', 'varB')"></input>
<h1 id="testResult"></h1>
```

Here's a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/ex09fx7k/.

Comment: While that works, the `addNumbers` is no longer useful for any other element types.

Comment: Then you can simply pass the ids of the elements as strings to the function. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes:

- You are adding up the inputs elements instead of their `value`.
- To convert its string value to a number, you can use unary `+`.
- Instead of inline event listeners, better use `addEventListener`.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('varA'),
    b = document.getElementById('varB'),
    result = document.getElementById("testResult");

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  addNumbers(a.value, b.value);
});

function addNumbers(n1, n2){
  result.textContent = +n1 + +n2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="15" id="varA">
<input type="text" value="30" id="varB">
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
<h1 id="testResult"></h1>
```