# Javascript: Get value from range sliding bar [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value from a range slider bar but getting this instead: `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

This is the setup I have:

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("ran");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliderbar = document.getElementById('ran');
sliderbar.onmouseup = function() {
  console.log(sliderbar); // alert shows [object HTMLInputElement]
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <span id="demo" style="font-weight: bold"></span><strong>miles</strong>
  <form>
    <input type='range' min='1' max="6" step="1" class="slider" id='ran' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to think the reference to a DOM element was the same as it’s value.

Comment: `alert(sliderbar.value);`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @mplungjan - Good point, did the same. Alternately, there *has* to be a "use `.value`" answer to a similar question, though I don't have an example handy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216153/javascript-error-object-htmlinputelementobject-htmlinputelement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205691/html-javascript-function-issue-object-htmlinputelement-error-output

Answer (score 2):

That's because `sliderBar` refers to the element. If you wants its value, use its `value` property, e.g.,`sliderBar.value` (or the slider-specific properties, if any, but I think slider just uses `value`).

Comment: this is a typo-type question in my opinion

Comment: @asifsaho - When an edit is rejected, don't keep repeating it.